# Storing the length of a dynamic array of struct

Tags: c

Can anyone help me with this? Say I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct mystruct{
    int data1;
    int data2;
}mystruct;
```

And I created an array of struct using the below code:

```
main(void) {
    mystruct **new_mystruct = function();
    ... need to know the length of new_mystruct here ...
}

mystruct **function(){
    ... code to determine length of array here ...
    mystruct **new_mystruct= malloc(length_of_array * sizeof(mystruct));
    ... code to fill array here ...
    return new_mystruct;
}
```

What is the best way to return the length of my array, assuming length_of_array is dynamically generated during the run time of my function?

I hope I'm making sense. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're declaring a double-pointer, but allocate for `mystruct` only. Drop one of the asterisks.

Comment: Just put NULL in the last element. Then you can do a while to count how many elems you have.

Comment: Seems like *linked list* would be one of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the length as a reference to the function, and have the function fill it in:

```
mystruct *function(size_t *size)
{
    /* ... */

    mystruct *new_mystruct = malloc(length_of_array * sizeof(mystruct))
    *size = length_of_array;

    /* ... */

    return new_mystruct;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* ... */

    size_t size;
    mystruct *new_mystruct = function(&size);

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This is the method I'm using as it is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Make wrapper struct:

```
typedef struct_array_
{
    mystruct * p;
    size_t size;
} struct_array;
```

Your creation function can return this by value:

```
struct_array create_array(size_t n)
{
    mystruct * p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);
    struct_array result = { p, n };
    return result;
}
```

You should make a matching clean-up function:

```
void destroy_array(struct_array a)
{
    free(a.p);
}
```

You can also make a `copy_array` function that uses `memcpy` to create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t function(MyStruct *mystruct)
{
    /*...*/
    mystruct = malloc(length_of_array * sizeof(MyStruct)); 
    /*...*/
    return length_of_array;   
}
```

and use

```
MyArray *new_array;
size_t lenght;

lenght = function(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either return a struct (or pointer to struct) that contains both the length and the pointer to the allocated array, or you can pass in a pointer to a variable to received the length.

```
int length;

mystruct **new_mystruct = function(&length);
```

I prefer the stuct approach.